# Why empty pages in my next js app have bundle size of 323kb?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have installed next bundle analyzer and ran build command and these are the results:

```
Route (pages)                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                        2.62 kB         325 kB
├   /_app                                    0 B             322 kB
├ ○ /_offline                                294 B           323 kB
├ ○ /[id]                                    2.96 kB         655 kB
├ ○ /404                                     185 B           323 kB
├ λ /account                                 6.64 kB         329 kB
├   └ css/bab50d110eee10ae.css               985 B
├ λ /additem                                 8.54 kB         640 kB
├ ○ /emptypage                               270 B           323 kB
```

I googled "how to reduce next js bundle size" and people recommended to do code splitting. I have done it, removed unecessary from my index page and nothing has improved.

I then created an emptypage.tsx just to see results and to my surprise first load was **323kb!**

What is going on how is this code below have 323kb bundle size?

```
import React from 'react';
function Emptypage() { return <div>This is empty page</div>; }

export default Emptypage;
```

Can someone explain how can this be possible?

Here are my next js bundle analyzer results:
[image]

Comment: Probably third party libs. When you run the analyser does it not open up a browser tab with a visual diagram? It should do. Would be useful to post the client and server tree maps.

Comment: @adsy I posted a screenshot, so does that mean that every dependancy is included in first load js? even if the page doesn't require any?

Comment: Right, so this is where code splitting comes in. Looks like the biggest offenders are the qrcode lib and lottie. Where are these imported? You probably need to split this specifically where it is used inside of the component that uses them (using react.lazy).

Comment: @adsy yes these are the libraries that i need to do something, but that would only optimise these pages right? and it would only reduce to my baseline which is 320kb due to overall dependancies? is that correct?

Comment: It depends, where abouts are they imported currently?

Comment: @adsy qrcodelibrary for example is only imported in "additem" page and nowhere else.

Comment: And just to double check, no component in the system imports `additem` page?

Comment: As a side note, im not fully familiar with if next does something special -- but in a normal webpack app, you would get the libs bundled for all pages if you use static ESM imports (which you will be). Thats because those libs could have side effects, and are statically linked. Next automated code splitting may be limited to only split off the page components themselves, and not static imports. In this case, you'd need to dynamically import those libs instead.